# .htaccess RewriteRule Condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.domain\.com?$
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/ipad%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

So my subdomain, **http://m.domain.com** is really pulling from **http://domain.com/ipad/**

Everything works fine if I type in: http://m.domain.com/shop-name/ it works perfectly.  But when I leave out the trailing slash and type in http://m.domain.com/shop-name it redirects to http://domain.com/ipad/shop-name/ which shouldn't happen, no one should see the ipad directory.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Is 'shop-name' a directory? Do you have access to the central Apache config file(s) (e.g. httpd.conf) or the `VirtualHost` section(s) for those hosts?

Comment: It is just another RewriteRule.  The real path is index.php?shop_name=whatever and it redirects to /shop-name/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because mod_dir is processing the request internally. When you access http://m.domain.com/shop-name and then it gets rewritten to http://domain.com/ipad/shop-name, mod_dir 302 redirects the browser to http://domain.com/ipad/shop-name/.

You can try handling the trailing slash in your RewriteRule. Probably a cleaner way of doing this, but something along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.domain\.com?$
# Has trailing slash in request, don't need to append one in the RewriteRule
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ./\ HTTP/1\.[01]$
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/ipad%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.domain\.com?$
# Missing trailing slash in request
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [^/]\ HTTP/1\.[01]$
# Request doesn't end with one of these extensions, 301 redirect to include trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule . http://m.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301]
```

EDIT: edited to address the 301 redirect of missing trailing slash

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, it worked!  In order to keep my links consistant, I would like to force a trailing slash on it so if they time in /shop-name it will redirect them to /shop-name/  it doesn't seem to do that at the moment.  I tried some different snippets in my htaccess file to force trailing slashes but cannot get it working.  I tried this:  

# Force Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

Comment: See the edited version of the 2nd Rewrite. When there is a missing trailing slash, instead of handing it off the domain.com *with* the trailing slash, 301 redirect the browser to include the slash